# Horizontal layout issues - divs overlapping

Tags: css, nowrap

I am having an issue with a horizontal layout: http://jsfiddle.net/GqH6s/4/

It seems the parent #content div gets its width from its first child (#projects), not the total of all its children.

I know I could work around it with jQuery but I'd like to use CSS if possible.

Thanks for your help!

The basic html:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="projects" class="section">
        <div class="block">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div id="profile" class="section">
        <div class="block">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div id="team" class="section">
        <div class="block">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
    #content {
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .section {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .block {
        white-space: normal;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want all elements to go left to right?

Comment: Yes I do. with a forced width of say 9000px on the #content div then the layout displays as I want it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the #profile and #team div's within the #project div so that they appear inline with the rest of the sections.

Should looks something like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks MathiasaurusRex, but the #content div is already a container div. If I can't simply apply styles to the current structure do I add another one around everything?

Comment: No. Just put the profile and team div's within the projects div, so they appear in line with the rest of the div's within that container.

Attached another image of what happens when you organize your div's with the above hierarchy.

Comment: @CarolineElisa you could also put a fixed width on #content, but that would cause there to be white space to the right of all your content if the user resizes his browser font.

Comment: Thanks again MathiasaurusRex but the children of #content are dynamically generated and will be anchor links in the navigation so they must be unique divs. Also, I do not want a fixed width on #content for this very reason.